# Create a EAR file compiling and getting compilation errors in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, compilation, ear

Well, I has a doubt about compiling a java project into eclipse.

**Note: My project is not using maven.**

If i want to get a .ear or .war file what is the way?

*I want to compile my project and get all compilation errors, because I change my jdk version, from jdk 1.5 to jdk 1.8*

And this is why I want to compile it getting my compilaion errors, to fix them and get the ear or war files

I mean, may I compile from project -> clean -> built automatically

And this gonna give me this kind of files?

Or i have to compile it from command prompt?

Hope you can help me, any idea is a good one.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Export option to create WAR or EAR file provided the project is created as Dynamic Web Project or Enterprise Application Project.

switch to java 8:
1. add JRE 8 libraries into your project classpath
2. change the compiler version to 1.8

Then select the Project->Build Automatically. you can see the errors in Error Log View or Markers View